# Creating a 100% page

Tags: html, css

I have a next problem, I have a simple task: Create a page that will contain header, footer and content.

Header, Footer - fixed size
Content - height is dynamic.

So the problem is when i created

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=1100" name="viewport">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

With this CSS:

```
html
{
height: 100%;
}

body
{
height: 100%;
}
```

It already has overflow (scroll on right side) why? If i set it to get all available space

Comment: This has already been answered but FYI, you shouldn't need to put 100% on the HTML tag. Here is a fiddle with some examples for responsive design: http://jsfiddle.net/GGSbp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `margin` which some user-agents apply to the `body` tag:

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

only apply height:100% to body not whole HTML :

CSS :

```
body
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If you don't apply the height to the `html` element, the `body `element's height will not stretch the entire page. The `body` element is contained within the `html` element, and if the `html` element has no height, the body will also have no height in this case.